Successfull login with authenticationManager but still 403 at any request
I'm trying to setup spring security with authorization through db and save user in security with authenticationManager.
In authorization service I'm setup GrantedAuthority and save Security User in Security Context
                Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = authoritiesService.userAuthorities(result.get(0).getSessionId());
                for (SimpleGrantedAuthority authority : grantedAuthorities) {
                    authorities.add(new Authorities(
                            (long) Integer.parseInt(authority.getAuthority().split(":")[0]),
                            authority.getAuthority().split(":")[1].split(",")[0].trim(),
                            authority.getAuthority().split(",")[1].split(", ")[0].trim()
                    ));
                }
                SecurityUser securityUser = new SecurityUser(login.getLogin(), result.get(0).getCompanyId(), result.get(0).getId(),
                        result.get(0).getSessionId(), login.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>(grantedAuthorities));
                SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
                context.setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(securityUser, login.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities));
                SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
                SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository = new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository();
                securityContextRepository.saveContext(context, httpRequest, httpResponse);

In my security configuration, I create an authenticationManager with a DaoAuthenticationProvider that uses a custom UserDetailsService
SecurityConfig:
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(@Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl") UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new MD5PasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/*",
                        "//*.{js,html,css}",
                        "/resources/",
                        "/static/",
                        "/webjars/",
                        "/public/",
                        "/swagger-ui/",
                        "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/swagger-resources",
                        "/swagger-resources/",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/webjars/",
                        "/v3/api-docs/",
                        "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    protected DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

UserDetails implementation:
    private final UserService userService;
    private final AuthoritiesService authoritiesService;

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserService userService, AuthoritiesService authoritiesService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.authoritiesService = authoritiesService;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User loggedUser = null;
        log.info(login);
        for (User user : userService.findAll().getResult()) {
            if (user.getLogin().equalsIgnoreCase(login)) {
                loggedUser = userService.findById(user.getId()).getResult().get(0);
            }
        }

        if (loggedUser.getIsActual() == Constants.BOOLEAN_NO) {
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("is-non-actual");
        }

        return SecurityUser.fromUser(loggedUser, authoritiesService);
    }

After success login I'm getting right authorities in response (and checking security context show the same), but still get a 403 on any request. What am I doing wrong?
Used to use spring boot 2.+, now switched to spring boot 3 and updated spring security, but it doesn't work now.
Using spring boot 3.3.3, spring security 6.3.0
UPD
As advised, I set logging to security. It seems as if nothing is saved to the context at all. Maybe I'm wrong.
login:


Securing POST /api/auth/login
Secured POST /api/auth/login


request to protected resource:


Securing GET /api/directories/bonus-kinds
Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext Saved request  http://127.0.0.1:6062/api/directories/bonus-kinds?continue to session
Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
Securing GET /error
Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
Saved request http://127.0.0.1:6062/error?continue to session
Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access



you need to know WHY you are getting 403, set logging level to debug with logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG so that you see the error. After that paste the error into question

I'm doing this in my custom authorization service and it's work for me
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(securityUser, login.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
Authentication auth = authenticateManager.authenticate(authReq);
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
context.setAuthentication(auth);
HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
session.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, context);

